# Install ruby version without patch updates (I know)

Tags: ruby, vim, rvm

Trying to determine if this is possible, not if this is advisable.

Let's say that I need ruby version `2.4.2` but the latest is `2.4.2-p1`. Is it possible to download the version without the patch?

For whatever reason, some plugins I am trying to use (command-t in vim) require exact patch version matches or else they will not work.  IE, ruby 2.4.2p0 vs 2.4.2p1 is significant. Because of this, I am trying to download using `rvm` a specific patched version of ruby but I do not see it. How can I get it?

I know the whole point of patch versions is to maintain compatibility.  This plugin requires it however.

I think to fix the plugin issue, I have to rebuild vim and then the plugin. This question just came up while trying to figure this out.

Comment: Sounds a crappy plugin... You can always resort to install Ruby from source.

Comment: I concur, the plugin authors are doing something they should not be doing.  The patch levels are bug fixes only, there is no reason for anything to require a specific patch level unless it *depends* on a *bug*, which is crazy.

Answer (score 1):

The short-term fix is that you need to recompile the vim plugin. This strict ruby version dependency is [well documented in the installation steps](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt#L82-L373).

However, I suspect this dependency check is *way* too tight. See [this discussion](https://github.com/wincent/command-t/issues/192) where others have pointed out a better solution the plugin should be using (and also an explanation from the author why the project currently works this way).

If you'd like to see this fixed "properly", then I'd suggest taking up the matter with the library's author(s) or fork it/submit a PR yourself.

...But either way, the right answer is **not** to install an older version of ruby (without patches).

Comment: That's the conclusion I've come to as well.  This question was more for the general question (without regard to if you should) install a specific patched version of ruby.

Comment: The short answer to that is: You can always install it from source.